# Find integer solutions to the equation $|x^2-y^n|=1$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find positive integer solutions to the equation $$|x^2-y^n|=1$$

I tried only the case $x^2-y^n=1$ and i cocluded the following

$y^n=x^2-1 \Rightarrow y^n=(x-1)(x+1)$

let $y$ to be odd then both $(x-1)$ and $(x+1)$ are odd and relatively prime. Thus there exist $a, b$ relatively prime such that $ab=y$. Hence $(x+1)=a^n$ and $(x-1)=b^n$

By subtracting the last two we get

$a^n-b^n=2 \\ \Rightarrow (a-b)(a^{n-1}+ \dots +b^{n-1})=2$

which yields contradicting results

Answer (score 0):

There is no contradiction if you re indeed looking for n. The thing is that for n bigger than 1 $(a+1)^n-a^n$ is bigger than 2 if a is at least 1. prove this. Of course, the thing is that the minimum difference between a and b is 1 so the above expression is also a minimum. This way then n=1. So, if you supposed n bigger than 1 indeed you have a contradiction.

Comment: For n=1 you have a-b=1 and a+b=2 and those give a=3/2 and b=1/2. contradiction since a,b are integers

Comment: you are right, neither n=1 works

Comment: wait, i said that in a hurry, its false, its fale, for n=1 you just get a-b=2 no contradiction

Comment: then it is a+b=1. but a,b are positive integers

Comment: no, that is false. you cant conclude that.

Comment: i think yes since for n=1 holds that (a-b)(a+b)=2 so one of the product must be equal to1 and the other must be equal to 2